# How to integrate a JFrame (Swing control) in JSP page in Netbeans IDE 6.5?

Tags: java, jsp, jframe

I want to integrate a JFrame (Swing control) in JSP page using Netbeans IDE 6.5. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or [webstart](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) (JNLP) which you embed in your HTML (JSP) page. The IDE is irrelevant here, it's just a development tool. Just write code accordingly.